# A word/expression for "Making a problem simpler by sharing it with a group of people".

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

One strategy to solve some problem or make it simpler, is to share it with someone who has a lot of knowledge about the subject. We use the idiom "Pick sb's brains" to express this way of breaking up the problem or this strategy. 
Another strategy is to share the problem with a group of people or friends, so that it becomes many brains unified in finding a solution for the same problem instead of 1 brain. Is there a word/expression used to refer to this strategy in English?

Comment: Crowd-sourcing?

Comment: Sorry, this is nothing to do with English or any other language; it’s purely about logic.
In language you’d have blocked yourself by the non-sensical suggestion that a problem could be made more or less simple.
A problem is as complex as it is. It might be stated more simply but that couldn’t change the problem. The same applies to any solution.
Clearly, the degree of effort needed to find a solution might change but please explain how that is the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

The typical term is **crowdsourcing.** A more specific term is **crowdsolving**:

> Crowdsolving, also stylized as crowd solving, is a form of problem solving that involves the collaboration of many people, communities, groups, or resources. It is a type of crowdsourcing, with focus on complex and intellectively demanding problems requiring considerable effort, and quality/ uniqueness of contribution.
>   [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crowdsolving)

Answer (score 0):

> **workshop**
>
> verb (transitive) To help a playwright revise a draft of (a play) by rehearsing it with actors and critiquing the results.
>
> verb (transitive, business) To improve through collaboration.

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/workshop

It's a newer word (as a verb); *[American Heritage](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=workshop&submit.x=0&submit.y=0)* and *[Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/workshop)* dictionaries have the former (theatrical) definition without the latter (business) definition.

Answer (score 0):

a [collaboration](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/collaboration)

1. the act of working with another or others [many brains] on a joint project
2. something created by working jointly with another or others

Comment: Also, cooperation!

Answer (score 0):

[Mindsharing](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Mindsharing)

> Mindsharing is a highly focused innovative business process where two or more people meet to share, plan and problem solve, either in person, or virtually. (UD)

Of course, this term can be considered as another definition for Crowdsourcing.